# Rename/Delete Misspelled Tag

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The [parametrized-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parametrized-constructor) tag is misspelled and probably unnecessary. It's not even clear whether it refers to generic or regular parameters.

Comment: [According to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parametrized), it's not a misspelling.

Comment: @Stijn It may technically be a valid alternative spelling, but google shows that "parameterized" is far more common/standard.

Comment: I get 4.4 million hits for "parameterized" and 1.4 million hits for "parametrized", so both are in widespread usage. Also see [EL&U: "Parametrise" or "parameterise"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79847/parametrise-or-parameterise-a-curve), which suggests that both are equally correct.

Comment: @Stijn I get 4k exact hits for "parametrized constructor" (plus a *Did you mean: parameterized constructor?*) and 101k exact hits for "parameterized constructor".

Comment: You can make this into a feature request so we can parameterise our preferred spelling ...

Comment: I also prefer the "parameterized" spelling, so that was made the master tag, and [parametrized-constructor] is a synonym of it.